# Use while loop to scan through pixels in a picture

Tags: jes

I can't figure out how to use `while` loops to scan through all the pixels.

I can do it with `for` loops,  but how to do it with using only while loops??

```
for x in range(0,width):
  for y in range(0,height):
    px = getPixels(pic,x,y)
```

## ___________________________

```
def question410():
  pic = makePicture(getMediaPath("barbara.jpg"))
  width = getWidth(pic)
  height = getHeight(pic)
  canvas = makeEmptyPicture(width,height)

  explore(pic)
  scale = 2


  x = 0
  y = 0
 while x < width:
   while y < height:
      px = getPixel(pic,x,y)
      colour = getColor(px)
      tgtPx = getPixel(canvas,x,y)
      setColor(tgtPx,colour)

      x=x+1
      y=y+1
      print x, y



  explore(canvas)
```

Comment: Have you made any attempt to code this yourself using `while` loops? If so, please share them.

Comment: I'm learning to do this in JES. I have tried something like 

    while x < width and y <height:
       px = getPixel(pic,x,y)
       colour = getColor(px)
       setColor(targetPx, colour)


i know i'm using while loop wrong.. i can't figure out how to use it to scan through my picture.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem appears to be the incrementation of the `x` variable inside the inner loop and not the outer loop.

```
while x < width:
  while y < height:
    # Do stuff
    y = y + 1
  x = x + 1
```

Answer (score -3):

You will have to create counter variables and ++ or -- them every loop untill the break condition appears.`
At example

```
x = 1
While (x != rangeofpixels) 
{ dostuff; x++ }
```